# NGINX configuration issue: Unable to access specific URLs

Tags: nginx, routes

I have an NGINX server with a configuration that includes proxying requests to different backend services based on the URL. However, I'm experiencing issues accessing specific URLs.

I have the following configuration in my NGINX server block:

```
  listen [::]:80;
  listen 443 ssl http2;
  listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
  ssl_certificate_key cert.key;
  ssl_certificate crt.crt;
  server_name banana.com;
  root <<my root dir>>;

  if ($scheme != "https") {
    rewrite ^ https://$host$uri permanent;
  }

  location ~ /.well-known {
    auth_basic off;
    allow all;
  }

  

  index index.html;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8024/;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
    proxy_pass_request_headers on;
    proxy_max_temp_file_size 0;
    proxy_connect_timeout 900;
    proxy_send_timeout 900;
    proxy_read_timeout 900;
    proxy_buffer_size 128k;
    proxy_buffers 4 256k;
    proxy_busy_buffers_size 256k;
    proxy_temp_file_write_size 256k;
  }
  error_page 404 /index.html;
```

I have successfully accessed my website at **banana.com**, but when I try to access URLs like **banana.com/item/1**, I receive a "**404 Not Found**" error. It seems that the proxy configuration is not handling these URLs properly.

Can anyone help me understand what changes are needed in my NGINX configuration to ensure that URLs like banana.com/item/1 are properly handled and not giving me 404 not found nginx page